# How to remove a NSButton from a NSCustom view programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to remove  a NSButton from a Customview programmatically ?
I used the below method but it didn't work .

[button removeFromSuperview];

Comment: Is NSCustom an actual class?

Comment: @Thilo its custom view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[YourButton removeFromSuperview];
```

**or**

Try

```
[YourButton setHidden:YES];
```

this might solve your problem :)